# How to write a python program for taking screenshots and displaying in label, automatically?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label, screenshot, display

I am making a GUI that would take a screenshot of the whole window and then paste it in a tkinter label automatically. I am able to take a screenshot and then save it but cannot past it inside a tkinter label.

Can someone please help with this program?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use the PIL package to handle images

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

ImagePath = ('Path For Image')
Image_open = Image.open(ImagePath)
Image_final = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image_open)

tk.Label(image=Image).pack()
```

Comment: Your code has few typo errors: `ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image)` should be `ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image_open)`, `tk.Label(image=Image)` should be `tk.Label(image=Image_final)`.  Also your code is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `
def open_img():
    x = askopenfilename()

    img = Image.open(x)

    img = img.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

    panel = Label(window, image=img)

    panel.image = img

` This is the code I had written, there is no error but when I open an image, it does not come in the GUI

Comment: @programmer You forgot calling `pack() / grid() / place()` on `panel` widget.